# about overwritting jpanel paintcomponent and relative position

Tags: java, swing

i am making a custom jpanel acting like a canvas for a game.
i was thinking of making the JPanel have a fixed size and use a LayoutManager to make it align to center.

but now i have the following problem:
if i draw something in my custom JPanel like,

```
@Override
public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

}
```

will the coordinates i give to the Graphics object be relative to my JPanel top left corner or relative to the inside of the window top left corner? (aka the rectangle within the decoration)

Comment: (1-) *will the coordinates i give to the Graphics object be relative to my JPanel top left corner or relative to the window top left corner?* - try it and let us know what happens. Note the method signature should be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`. And the first statement should be `super.paintComponent(g)` to make sure the entire background of the panel is cleared.

Comment: i was mostly theorising about it there, i asked because as im not familiar with swing out of custom jpanel (thanks old game dev tutorial ^^) so i thought it would take me a lot of time with the risk of making mistakes and missunderstanding the result. about ``super.paintComponent(g)``, im just drawing a rectangle over it instead, is that faster?

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do painting. Download the working examples and play with them. Don't theorize. Ask specific questions when you have a problem.

Comment: The coordinates are relative to the drawing JPanel.  It would have been pretty simple to test.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc well i tried to test it, i got the opposite result :/ , thats why i asked the question, i dont understand it enough to test it efficiently myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simple example I created for a different question.

Change the location of the rectangles and see where they wind up.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShapesExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles;

    public ShapesExample() {
        rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(41, 41, 20, 20));
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Shapes Example");

        add(new DrawingPanel());
        
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ShapesExample();
            }
        });
    }

    class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
                g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 
                        rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does that answer the question? tell me if im wrong but in your example both the window and the jpanel have the same origin (just to be sure, by "window" i meant the inside of the window, i wasnt including the border, i will edit the question if that was unclear)

Comment: @R.L: Your question was unclear.  When people say "window" (JFrame), they include all the decorations.  I wrote the code according to the specifications I had at the time. if you want something else, modify the code yourself.  Bless your heart.

Comment: thanks for trying to help and sorry for the lack of clarification then :/